# How to add a custom claim in an extension grant type only

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to add a custom claim in my extension grant type.
and my code is like the following in my class that implement IExtensionGrantValidator, but the resulting token from this doesn't contain the added custome_claim

```
        public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
        var userToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("token");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken))
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
            return;
        }

        var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken);
        if (result.IsError)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
            return;
        }

        var sub = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;

        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, "graph_delegation", new List<Claim> { new Claim("custome_claim", "Hello from the custom grant") });
    }
```

Comment: do u ever got to know how to do it ?

Comment: @Sana, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The process consists of three parts and is identical for issuing any access token with custom claims, not only for extension grant:

*Firstly* the claim has to be **requested** by the client using an appropriate scope. On the Identity Server side `GetApiResources()` method must add that claim type into the appropriate scope.

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources(){
        return new List<ApiResource>{
             new ApiResource{
                    Name = "API 1",
                    DisplayName = "API 1",
                    Scopes = {
                        new Scope {
                            Name = "my-api",
                            UserClaims =  {
                                JwtClaimTypes.SessionId,
                                JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                                Constants.TenantIdClaimType,
                                "custom_claim" }
                        }
                    }
                }               
            };
      }
```

*Secondly* the claim has to be issued somehow -- one way is to use `GrantValidationResult` constructor, as described in the original post above, to put it in.

*And finally* the requested claim should be added to the IssuedClaims collection for the token. That is the job for a `ProfileService` implementation. A custom `ProfileService` should be implemented and registered in IdSrv startup as the following:

```cs
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        ***
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetApiResources())
        .AddExtensionGrantValidator<DelegationGrantValidator>()
        .AddProfileService<ExtendedProfileService>();
```

Where in

```cs
    public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
```

the row: `context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);` will do the job.
It's not necessary to implement `IProfileService` from scratch, but enough to derive an existing one and override only one method.